# Java programming error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:"

Tags: java

New Java programmer. I have no idea of what's causing this error.

Everything compiled fine until I added the if statements.
Still learning how to debug.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class VelocityTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Chapter3 example
        // 
        
        int time2, time1;
        double distance1, distance2, velocity;
        double velocityValue = 60.0;
        
        
        
        String input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time 2");
        time2= Integer.parseInt(input); // Enter 4 (hrs)
        
        input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time 1");
        time1= Integer.parseInt(input); 
        
        input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter distance 2");
        distance2 = Integer.parseInt(input); 
        
        input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter distance 1");
        distance1 = Integer.parseInt(input); 
        
        velocity = (distance2 - distance1)/(time2 - time1);
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("the velocity is " + velocity);
        
        
        if (velocity > velocityValue) {
            System.out.println("the velocity is greater than 60");
        }
            
        else {
            System.out.println("the velocity is less than 60");
        }
            
            }
        


    }

}
```

Comment: The problem (the runtime exception) is caused by running a program that has not compiled correctly.  The solution is to fix the compilation errors **before** you attempt to run the program.  We don't know what the compilation errors are because you haven't told us.

Comment: You seem to have an extra `}` at the of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you formatted your code properly using an IDE, you would have noticed that you have an extra closing brace `}` at the end.

Comment: You should *also* have noticed the compilation error message, irrespective of using an IDE or not.